# Synchronize on DataOutputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, dataoutputstream

I have gone through so many tutorials on Synchronization now that my head is spinning.  I have never truly understood it :(.

I have a Java server(**MainServer**), that when a client connects creates a new thread(**ServerThread**) with a DataOutputStream.

The client talks to the **ServerThread** and the **ServerThread** responds.  Every now and then the **MainServer** will distribute a message to all clients utilizing each **ServerThread's** DataOutputStream object.

I am quite certain that every now and then my issue is because both the **MainServer** and **ServerThread** are trying to send something to the client at the same time.  Therefore I need to lock on the DataOutputStream object.  For the life of me I cannot understand this concept any further.  Every example I read is confusing.

What is the correct way to handle this?

**ServerThread's send to client method:**

```
public void replyToOne(String reply){
    try {
        commandOut.writeUTF(reply);
        commandOut.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.fatal("replyToOne", e);
    }
    logger.info(reply);
}
```

**MainServer's distribute to all clients method:**

```
public static void distribute(String broadcastMessage){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object[]> entry : AccountInfoList.entrySet()) {
        Object[] tmpObjArray = entry.getValue();
        DataOutputStream temporaryCOut = (DataOutputStream) tmpObjArray[INT_COMMAND_OUT]; //can be grabbed while thread is using it
        try {
            temporaryCOut.writeUTF(broadcastMessage);
            temporaryCOut.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("distribute: writeUTF", e);
        }
        logger.info(broadcastMessage);  
    }
}
```

I am thinking I should have something like this in my **ServerThread** class.

```
public synchronized DataOutputStream getCommandOut(){
    return commandOut;
}
```

Is it really that simple?  I know this has likely been asked and answered, but I don't seem to be getting it still, without individual help.

Comment: There's your problem: *Every now and then the MainServer will distribute a message to all clients utilizing each ServerThread's DataOutputStream object.* .... WHY? why not just call a method on the ServerThread instance?, then let the ServerThread send the message to the client at an appropriate time....?

Comment: Agree with @rolfl, I would strongly recommend you read http://www.cs.unicam.it/culmone/?download=java_concurrency_in_practice.pdf

Comment: So that would fix the issue because the ServerThread is single threaded access to DataOutputStream... good point.  Pulling my hair out here, is it really that simple?

Comment: @shazin thank you I will give it a good read, hope it helps me actually understand it.  For now with rolfl's suggestion it makes logical sense to avoid multithreaded access, but I'm sure I'll need to know for the future. thanks both of you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were me.....

I would have a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) on each client-side thread. Then, each time the client thread has a moment of idleness on the socket, it checks the queue. If there's a message to send from the queue, it sends it.

Then, the server, if it needs to, can just add items to that queue, and, when the connection has some space, it will be sent.

Add the queue, have a method on the ServerThread something like:

```
addBroadcastMessage(MyData data) {
    broadcastQueue.add(data);
}
```

and then, on the socket side, have a loop that has a timeout-block on it, so that it breaks out of the socket if it is idle, and then just:

```
while (!broadcastQueue.isEmpty()) {
    MyData data = broadcastQueue.poll();
    .... send the data....
}
```

and you're done.

The `LinkedBlockingQueue` will manage the locking and synchronization for you.

Comment: Excellent, already switched some of the issues to this and spot checked my work... works like a charm.  Am going to finish up the rest.  Will make any future debugging simpler.  Sending everything from the 'ServerThread' designated to that client will make it simpler.  Thanks again so much for the help!

Comment: ugh this wont work after all... my ServerThread's commandIn.readUTF() will block so even if the queue gets items added to it, it will be waiting on client request messages first before it depletes its queue messages at the top of the loop.  Is there any way to make adding a message to the queue unblock the commandIn.readUTF()?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

Every statement modifying the `DataOutputStream` should be `synchronized` on this `DataOutputStream` so that it is not concurrently accessed (and thus do not have any concurrent modification):

```
public void replyToOne(String reply){
    try {
        synchronized(commandOut) {    // writing block
            commandOut.writeUTF(reply);
            commandOut.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.fatal("replyToOne", e);
    }
    logger.info(reply);
}
```

And:

```
public static void distribute(String broadcastMessage){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object[]> entry : AccountInfoList.entrySet()) {
        Object[] tmpObjArray = entry.getValue();
        DataOutputStream temporaryCOut = (DataOutputStream) tmpObjArray[INT_COMMAND_OUT]; //can be grabbed while thread is using it
        try {
            synchronized(temporaryCOut) {  // writing block
                temporaryCOut.writeUTF(broadcastMessage);
                temporaryCOut.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("distribute: writeUTF", e);
        }
    logger.info(broadcastMessage);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Jean thank you so much for the insight.  I really appreciate this.  It helps me to feel a little bit less lost.  In order to keep it as simple as possible I am going to avoid multithreading and just use the queue solution since I have 1 thread per client anyways.  That being said, this still makes me feel more confident in my grasp. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just putting my 2 cents:

The way I implement servers is this:

Each server is a thread with one task only: listening for connections. Once it recognizes a connection it generates a new thread to handle the connection's input/output (I call this sub-class ClientHandler).

The server also keeps a list of all connected clients.

ClientHandlers are responsible for user-server interactions. From here, things are pretty simple:

Disclaimer: there are no try-catches blocks here! add them yourself. Of course you can use thread executers to limit the number of concurrent connections.

Server's `run()` method:

```
@Override
public void run(){
 isRunning = true;
 while(isRunning){
  ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(serversocket.accept());
  clients.add(ch);
  ch.start();
 }
}
```

ClientHandler's ctor:

```
public ClientHandler(Socket client){
 out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
 in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
}
```

ClientHandler's `run()` method:

```
@Override
public void run(){
 isConnected = true;
 while(isConnected){
  handle(in.readObject());
 }
}
```

and `handle()` method:

```
private void handle(Object o){
 //Your implementation
}
```

If you want a unified channel say for output then you'll have to synchronize it as instructed to avoid unexpected results.

There are 2 simple ways to do this:

1. Wrap every call to output in synchronized(this) block
2. Use a getter for output (like you did) with synchronized keyword.

Comment: This setup is almost identical to what I have going.  I just simplified for purposes of my question.  MyServer (brains with connectionHandler thread), every connection spawns MyCommandHandler thread with input/output streams to client.  When MyServer and MyCommandHandler were competing over the same DataOutputStream I got my issues, now with wrapping the WriteUTF() calls in synchronized, hopefully I won't see it anymore.  Appreciate your 2 cents(positive affirmation)!! :D